# PyQt5 ListWidget add list items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

while learning PyQt5 i found a little problem( maybe a bug) in the ListWidget Widget (and all other widgets)

the `ListWidget` have a `addItem` method overloaded :
( the code is in c++ but this is the same interface in pyqt )

```
void    addItem(const QString &label)
void    addItem(QListWidgetItem *item)
void    addItems(const QStringList &labels)
```

so the problem is that in PyQt5 there is no more `QStringList` type, and i should use a simple list of strings instead of the `QStringList`

but when i receive and error telling me that no method match the given paramaters :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    listWidget.addItem(ls)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addItem(self, QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  addItem(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

Here is my code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    listWidget = QListWidget()
    listWidget.show()

    ls = ['test', 'test2', 'test3']

    listWidget.addItem('test')
    listWidget.addItem('test2')
    listWidget.addItem('test3')

    listWidget.addItem(ls)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a list you must use the function `addItems()`.
Change:

```
listWidget.addItem(ls)
```

to

```
listWidget.addItems(ls)
```